# AudioInputStream Pop sound at the end of an 8-bit WAV sound Mac OSX [Java 1.7+ bug]

Tags: java, wav

I am making a video game and I've started implementing sounds to it, all of my sounds are .wav files and are 8-bit. (example sound https://ufile.io/ipbz2).

Now the issue I'm facing is that it seems like on Mac OSX there's a strange popping noise when playing the sound (at the end).

My example code

```
public static void playSound() throws Exception {
    final Clip clip = (Clip)AudioSystem.getLine(new Line.Info(Clip.class));
    clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("/Users/Phil/Desktop/2393.wav")));
    clip.start();

    // Sleep for 5 sec so it plays the sound.
    Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

Things I've already tried

- Running the Code on Java JDK 1.6. Works fine but my whole project isn't compliant with that, I also tried making an external library (.jar) and exporting that with jdk 1.6 but once I used that library it in my client it started cutting out.
- Playing the sound and cut the last 10ms. This solution seems to be alright but when I start playing a lot of sounds the popping noise starts again.
- Using online tools to convert the wav from 8 bit to 16 bit, this solution seems to work but my filesize went from 25kb to 100kb, not a great result when I have 1000+ sound files.

If you have any suggestions what I could try please let me know! I'm willing to try a lot!

Comment: `.wav` files are typically uncompressed - if you’re that worried about size, why aren’t you using a compressed format? Your sample audio file contains a lot of silence which would compress very well.

Comment: Vorbis (`.ogg`), AAC (`.m4a`) and MP3 (`.mp3`) are all under a quarter the size of the original `.wav`